I get "AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches: /Index /_Host /_Host" after I had accidantly renamed the index file
My Blazor server side app's home page (index.razor) was normally opening with addres https://mywebsite:4444/ quite normal.
I do not know exactly, but I think I have accidantly renamed or copied my index file, but brought it back again to the original status. I can verify that from older version backups of my project. I have even deleted my index file and copied one from the older stable versions of my app. I haven't done anything with the _Host.cshtml file.
But know when I publish my app and open https://mywebsite:4444/ I get always "AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches: /Index /_Host /_Host" Error. I can open each page when I add the pagename to the address. I can also navigate to my homepage over the navigation bar home page link.
What do I have to check exactly?
I have googled but not found any solution matching my case:
My Index looks like:
@page "/"
<h1>Home</h1>
<Div>
   <img src="images/Main_Logo.png" height="127" width="512"  />
</Div>

My _Host.cshtml file starts with
@page "/"
@namespace WebApplication7.Pages
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@{
    Layout = null;
}
...

